Excel-365 functions don't work as expected
While creating the solution for "How to Merge Rows values into a Column on a prior Row?" I composed the formula:
[G11] =LET(
  c,COLUMNS(Table1),
  at_l,INDEX(Table1,0,c),
  n,ROWS(Table1),
  af,FILTER(HSTACK(Table1,SEQUENCE(n)),Table1[Product]<>"null"),
  aw,DROP(VSTACK(INDEX(af,0,c+1),n+1),1),
  HSTACK(
    TAKE(af,,c),
    BYROW(
      SEQUENCE(ROWS(af)),
      LAMBDA(i,
        TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,
          DROP(TAKE(at_l,INDEX(aw,i)-1),INDEX(af,i,c+1))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

Manually checking it has no error, but it doesn't work as depicted below:

The data table:



#
QTY
Product
Option
Item Name




1
3
CHR124

Chair


null
null
null
.FOC
Fog


2
1
SFA478

Sofa


null
null
null
.A
A


null
null
null
.B
B


null
null
null
.C
C


null
null
null
.D
D


null
null
null
.E
E


null
null
null
.F
F


null
null
null
.G
G


null
null
null
.H
H


3
2
TBL8954

Table


null
null
null
.I
I


null
null
null
.J
J


null
null
null
.K
K


null
null
null
.L
L


null
null
null
.M
M


null
null
null
.N
N


null
null
null
.O
O


null
null
null
.P
P



To debug the issue, I composed the intermediate formula:
[G15] =LET(
  c,COLUMNS(Table1),
  at_l,INDEX(Table1,0,c),
  n,ROWS(Table1),
  af,FILTER(HSTACK(Table1,SEQUENCE(n)),Table1[Product]<>"null"),
  aw,DROP(VSTACK(INDEX(af,0,c+1),n+1),1),
  HSTACK(
    af,
    aw
  )
)

and then
[G19] =BYROW(
  SEQUENCE(ROWS(G15:G17)),
  LAMBDA(i,
    TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,
      DROP(TAKE(Table1[Item Name],INDEX(M15:M17,i)-1),INDEX(G15:L17,i,6))
    )
  )
)

which is also doesn't work.
But it can work with small modification:
[I19] =SCAN("",
  SEQUENCE(ROWS(G15:G17)),
  LAMBDA(a,i,
    TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,
      DROP(TAKE(Table1[Item Name],INDEX(M15:M17,i)-1),INDEX(G15:L17,i,6))
    )
  )
)

But the main formula with this modification still doesn't work:
=LET(
  c,COLUMNS(Table1),
  at_l,INDEX(Table1,0,c),
  n,ROWS(Table1),
  af,FILTER(HSTACK(Table1,SEQUENCE(n)),Table1[Product]<>"null"),
  aw,DROP(VSTACK(INDEX(af,0,c+1),n+1),1),
  HSTACK(
    TAKE(af,,c),
    SCAN("",
      SEQUENCE(ROWS(af)),
      LAMBDA(a,i,
        TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,
          DROP(TAKE(at_l,INDEX(aw,i)-1),INDEX(af,i,c+1))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

I did more debug modifications but get nothing finally. Even Excel crashed when I replaced TEXTJOIN by REDUCE.
I found the solution for the question, but the issue described above still irritate me.
It smells as an Excel bug but can anybody comment it or provide an explanation?

Add intersection: =LET(  c,COLUMNS(Table1),  at_l,INDEX(Table1,0,c),  n,ROWS(Table1),  af,FILTER(HSTACK(Table1,SEQUENCE(n)),Table1[Product]<>"null"),  aw,DROP(VSTACK(INDEX(af,0,c+1),n+1),1),  HSTACK(    TAKE(af,,c),    BYROW(      SEQUENCE(ROWS(af)),      LAMBDA(i,        TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,          DROP(TAKE(at_l,@INDEX(aw,i)-1),@INDEX(af,i,c+1)))))))

We need to tell Excel it's one value only, not an array, even if the array is one actually. At least that's how I would explain it.

It can be the answer. You can edit your answer with this solution.

Overwrote my initial answer with this (feel free to edit it, since I'm working from my mobile phone)

=LET(
  c,COLUMNS(Table1),
  at_l,INDEX(Table1,0,c),
  n,ROWS(Table1),
  af,FILTER(HSTACK(Table1,SEQUENCE(n)),Table1[Product]<>"null"),  
  aw,DROP(VSTACK(INDEX(af,0,c+1),n+1),1),
  HSTACK(
    TAKE(af,,c),
    BYROW(
      SEQUENCE(ROWS(af)),
      LAMBDA(i,
        TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,
          DROP(TAKE(at_l,@INDEX(aw,i)-1),@INDEX(af,i,c+1)))))))

Adding intersection @ to the INDEX tells Excel the array is a single value (even if it is).

Brilliant. Had no idea about it.

The explanation of BYROW/BYCOL behavior is provided in Microsoft Excel "#VALUE error" when using BYROW and LAMBDA function
